# Binding does not update. (Property change of Parent?!)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a problem with updating my bindings.
But I think the easiest way to explain my problem is my code:

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Converter:Converter_Position x:Key="Position"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Position.X, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Position, Converter={StaticResource PositionToStartPosition}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

If I change the Text of the first TextBox the second TextBox does not update.

**My Converter:**

```
class Converter_Position : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type t, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        RaPoint Position = value as RaPoint;
        return Position.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type t, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

**Bond Class:**

```
public class RaPoint : INodifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public RaPoint()
        {
            X = 0;
            Y = 0;
        }

        public RaPoint(double X, double Y)
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }

        private const string XPropertyName = "X";
        private double _X;
        public double X
        {
            get
            {
                return _X;
            }
            set
            {
                _X = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(XPropertyName);
            }
        }

        private const string YPropertyName = "Y";
        private double _Y;
        public double Y
        {
            get
            {
                return _Y;
            }
            set
            {
                _Y = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(YPropertyName);
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("X:{0} Y:{1}" , X.ToString(), Y.ToString());
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

**DataContext:**

```
private const string PositionPropertyName = "Position";
private RaPoint _Position = new RaPoint();
public RaPoint Position
{
    get
    {
        return _Position;
    }
    set
    {
        _Position = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(PositionPropertyName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the `DataContext` of your Window with a `RaPoint` instance (`Position` property), then you should try binding this way:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=X, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource PositionToStartPosition}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Basically, a data binding establishes a connection between two properties of different objects. In the first line you are binding a property of the object you set in the the DataContext.  `Path` is used to specify a property of that object or might point to a property of a property (imagine X  would have a property Z, then you could do something like `Path=X.Z`).

About the second `TextBox`, If you don't specify binding's `Source`, `Path`, `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` the Binding uses control's DataContext. The `DataContext` is passed through the visual tree from upper element (e.g. Window) to the lower ones (`TextBox` in your case).

But those suggestions are not going to resolve your problem. When you change the value of `X` in the first TextBox, the `Position`property never change, so the `RaisePropertyChanged` is not going to be called and the second TextBox  is not going to be updated with the new value of X. If you want to have a TextBox with both values of `X` and `Y`, then use a MultiBinding. In your Window/UserControl do this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=X, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Position}">
          <Binding Path="X" />
          <Binding Path="Y" />
       </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

And change your converter this way:

```
public class Converter_Position : IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return String.Format("X:{0} Y:{1}", values[0],values[1]); 
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the converter is only getting used once, upon load. The `Position` `DataContext` never changes, so there is no point in having a `RaisePropertyChnage` inside the setter of the Position property. Remove that.

```
public RaPoint Position
{
    get
    {
        return _Position;
    }
    set
    {
        _Position = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(PositionPropertyName);
    }
}
```

to

```
public RaPoint Position
{
   get; set;
}
```

The next thing is that you want the `TextBox` to be updated whenever `X` does, so ideally, you do not want to bind to simply just `Position` (since the `DataContext` is only getting changed once), you want to bind to `Position.X` because that's where the property changed event is. By doing so, the converter will evaluate each time `X` changes. You also want just the `Position` class though, passed in the converter. You will need to update the converter so that the `Position` is passed into it. The easiest way is to use a MultiValuConverter to pass into the Parameter object and also Paramter.X (which is going to be used to monitor the changes).

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PositionToStartPosition}">
                <Binding Path="Position.X" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                <Binding Path="Position" />
            </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Lastly, update your converter:

```
class Converter_Position : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type t, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        RaPoint Position = values[1] as RaPoint;
        return Position.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object[] values, Type t, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```